# Is the turtlebot bumper sensor being used by the naviation stack?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My turtlebots don't respond to the bumper sensor when navigating using AMCL.  That is, there appears to be no default behavior related to the bumper. Of course, I am planning to fix this in my own logic, but I wanted to be sure that I am not missing some basic functionality or configuration step.

That is, is there some out of the box bumper functionality included, or is it assumed that we will build that into our own behaviors (such as to back up, re-orient, etc.)?  If we should build it ourselves, is it simply a matter of subscribing to the sensor_state messages to get the bumper state?  Will I need to cancel my AMCL goal before backing up?

After looking around, all I could find is this enhancement request:
https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/35

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36676/is-the-turtlebot-bumper-sensor-being-used-by-the-naviation-stack?/) by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 332 on 2012-06-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bumper sensor is used to stop the turtlebot at the lowest level: [relevant code](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/e47d5a1dca1c/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py#l429)

Once the navigation stack realizes it isn't moving even after sending velocity commands, it may (if you've enabled it) go into recovery behaviour. The default behaviour (which the default turtlebot launch files use) is [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base#Expected_Robot_Behavior)

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1